# C++ operator overloading stream requires cast

Tags: c++

I'm overloading some operation on a class and notice that on the ostream overloading one of the values is not as expected. Here is the example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Simple{
    int x;
public:
    Simple() : x(0){}
    Simple(int i) : x(i){}
    const Simple& operator+(const Simple& s){
        return Simple(x + s.x);
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Simple& s);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Simple& s){
    os << s.x;
    return os;
}

int main(void){
    Simple s1(2);
    Simple s2(3);
    cout << "s1 = " << s1 << endl;
    cout << "s2 = " << s2 << endl;
    cout << "s1 + s2 = ";
    Simple s3 = s1 + s2;
    cout << s1 << " + " << s2 <<  " = " << s1 + s2 << endl;
    cout << s1 << " + " << s2 <<  " = " << static_cast<Simple>(s1 + s2) << endl;
    cout << "s3 = " << s3 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It produces the following output:

s1 = 2

s2 = 3

s1 + s2 = 2 + 3 = -872483744

2 + 3 = 5

s3 = 5

Is this an issue with how I am overloading, or will the cast always be required to get my expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `operator+` returns a reference to a local variable, and a temporary at that.

It's a *dangling reference*.

`operator+` should return by value.